# Bitcoind implementation in online website

Tags: bitcoind

im new to this world and i would like to understand better. 
i have an online platform and i would like to recive bitcoin payments from end costumers directly to my wallet without using 3d party.

i understood that Bitcoind is one of my options. 
actually i would like to implement a bottom in my website.

let me know if this flow is possible:
1. end costumer want to deposit BTC.
2. he gets unique address for his transaction that is connected to my wallet directly.
3. waiting for at least 1 confirmation from the Blockchain network.
4. his account credited in the platform.

thanks,

Comment: Using only 1 confirmation is extremely risky. Blockchain forks for reorganization of one block is very frequent and would be a big attack vector that can be exploited. The recommended waiting time is 6 blocks, but if you are willing to take some risk, you can use 2-3 blocks.

Comment: hey, thank you for your quick response. 
i will take your advise regarding the confirmations.

the flow that i wrote above is correct? possible?